Update Normals on Post Rigify Mesh
Novice Blender user here. I've been trying to get a custom Blender model to show up in Unity. This has been a bit of a headache. But the short of it is: The model I imported to Unity is transparent. A google search online suggests that I need to "select all of the faces of my character mesh in Blender and flip the normals" (this makes sense to me, basically turning the UV's rightside out).
However, I created my model using Rigify to make some animations. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access and edit the characters mesh normals at this point. It seems like it would be possible but I can't figure out the method.
I've added some images to better capture my concern:
My Blender setup, post Rigify: 
A new un-rigified setup: 
Here is a bigger image in case it helps (includes the View Layer): 
And here is the file I am using:

Here is the file: 

Please edit your question and add the above link directly into it. - Links in comments can easily be missed. Your character's normals are actually correct but you would normally select your character in Object mode, go into Edit mode, select All then hit Shift-N to recalculate them. Can't help with your Unity problem I'm afraid.

I've checked your file. There are two things here, 1) editing the normals of a rigged model (=the answer to your question) and 2) the transparency problem.
1) The answer to your question and a few side notes:
The normals of your model are completely fine. You can check them easily with the Face Orientation overlay. The colors mean the following: blue=outside, red=inside. If you see a red color on the outside then it's bad and the face/normal needs to be flipped.
You can do this in Edit mode. Select the Mesh object, go to Edit mode, activate Face Selection mode (2), and select the flipped faces. Finally, choose menu Mesh > Normals > Flip or Recalculate Outside (shortcut: Shift+N)
It's important to know that Blender is very context-sensitive. If you do an action it matters

where your mouse pointer is (=active window) and
which object(s) you have selected.

Note that there is the so-called active object (=orange color in the outliner) and the selected objects (=red color in the outliner).
For example, you did 2 different things here:

 <- here you have selected the Mesh object (=orange "triangle" icon in the outliner) and going to edit the mesh.

 <- here you have selected the Armature object (orange "stick figure" icon in the outliner) and you're going to edit the bones of it. If the model is rigged, the Mesh object is a child of the Armature object. Expand the Armature object to see its children. So the answer to the questions is: If you want to flip the normals of a rigged model, select and edit the Mesh object, not the Armature object ;-)

another example: if you have your mouse pointer in the 3D view and press Ctrl+A you will get the Apply menu for objects. But if you move the mouse pointer over a modifier in the modifier stack and press the same shortcut, Blender will immediately apply the modifier under the mouse pointer.


2) Fixing the Unwanted Transparency:
It's the Alpha value of the shader. A value of 0 means fully transparent, and 1 means fully opaque. The 0.250 value makes the model 75% transparent. So, it's easy to fix:


go to the Shading workspace
select the mesh of the bear (Cube)
set the Alpha value of the Principled BSDF node to 1.0

Note that the Material Preview does not show transparency by default. You need to activate it in the Material Settings panel tab. Set Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed or Alpha Blend as shown here: Partial transparency of fabric in EEVEE

Superb answer. Thank you for your in depth explanation!
